# GCP vpc vm private access to googleapis blocked (firewall not working)

Tags: networking, router, routing, firewall, google-cloud-platform

According to the [GCP doc](https://cloud.google.com/vpc-service-controls/docs/set-up-private-connectivity?hl=RU), for security reasons, we restrict egress requests from vpc instances to only `199.36.153.4/30` by creating a high priority firewall rule -- allowing egress traffic, with next hop being "default internet gateway", allowing tcp:443 protocol.

However, `ping 199.36.153.4` fails, and `traceroute 199.36.153.4` gives me the following:

```
traceroute to 199.36.153.4 (199.36.153.4), 30 hops max, 60 byte packets
 1  gateway (172.17.0.1)  0.189 ms  0.026 ms  0.033 ms
 2  * * *
 3  * * *
... * * *
30  * * *
```

which shows that the routing is correct (nexthop going to default internet gateway is expected), but the packet was blocked by later router.

I tried to change the firewall rule to allow all protocols. Still the packet is blocked like above.

Can anyone point me to some other things I can look at? I am really stuck on this and could not make progress further

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turned out `restricted.googleapis.com` only opens communication for TCP:443. Even `ping`, which uses ICMP protocol, is blocked by `restricted.googleapis.com`

In the end, I used `nmap -p 443 restricted.googleapis.com`, or `telnet www.googleapis.com 443` which shows the connection is good.

Comment: Could you please provide some more details regarding this fire wall rule. like why we need to set this up and how and from where we can check the connectivity?